# DRL not fired when loaded from non-classpath resource

Tags: java, spring, classpath, drools

I have a Spring application that uses Drools rules. When the rules are packaged with the application's war file, they are all loaded correctly and fired correctly. However, a recent requirement has dictated that these rules should be placed external to the application so that a rules developer can edit them while the application is running. During testing we have found that the rules load correctly BUT only two of them fire even if we use the same data as before when all the rules used to fire.
Has anybody else used this approach and faced the same issue? I am using Drools 5.4.0.

Thanks for any help

Angus

Comment: Are you creating and starting a new session after the rules have been edited?

Comment: No. This is on start up of the application even before any edits have been made.

Comment: Then it is impossible to advise without a full example reproducing your problem. It may be reduced to the essentials, but it must show the rules before the edit, the facts inserted to fire some rules and other changes to WM, the rules after the edit, any later inserts and WM changes and which rules you expect to fire, and the Java app driving the process. - However, let me add that modifying the knowledge base on the fly is rather iffy. It would be best to dispose the session and restart using the new, edited knowledge base. The tricky part in any case is the state of the WM during the switch.